# Change cwd before running tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, pytest

I have a bunch of `unittest` test cases in separate directories. There is also a directory which just contains helper scripts for the tests. So my file tree looks like this

```
test_dir1
test_dir2
test_dir3
helper_scripts
```

Each python file in `test_dir*` will have these lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../helper_scripts')
import helper_script
```

This all works fine, as long as I run the tests from within their directory. However, I would like to be at the project root and just run:

```
py.test
```

and have it traverse all the directories and run each test it finds. The problem is that the tests are being run from the wrong directory, so the `sys.path.append` doesn't append the `helper_scripts` directory, it appends the parent of the project root. This makes all the imports fail with an `Import Error`.

Is there a way to tell `py.test` to run the test scripts from their directory? ie. change the cwd before executing them? If not, is there another test runner I can use that will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is structure my project like this:

```
myproject/
    setup.py
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test_dir1/
                test_mymodule.py
            helper_scripts/
                __init__.py
                helper_script.py
```

For running tests, I use a virtualenv with `myproject` installed in development mode using one of the following commands in the `myproject` root directory:

```
pip install -e .
python setup.py develop
```

Now in `test_mymodule.py` I can just say

```
from myproject.tests.helper_scripts import helper_script
```

I can then just run `pytest` and there's no need to change the working directory in tests at all.

See Pytest's [Good Integration Practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) for a great summary of pros and cons for different project directory structures.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you instead configure your environment so that `import helper_scripts` will work regardless of the current directory. This is the recommended approach.

If you absolutely must though, you can use relative imports instead:

```
from .. import helper_script
```

Comment: How exactly do you do that? Do you have to change the current directory within the script?

Answer (score -2):

```
os.chdir("newdir")
```

will change your current working directory

Comment: FYI: Found this answer in low quality review queue.  **Looks OK**.

Comment: Yes but I would rather not modify every python file. I'm looking for some argument or setting for py.test (or another test runner) that will tell it to first change to the directory of the python file, before executing it.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me, I don't think you should need to change the working directory in tests in the first place, at least not for just importing helpers. See my answer above for one possible way to make helpers importable.